# useradd - not working with -p option

Tags: php, linux

I have a PHP script that is trying to add a user. Here's a simplified snippet:

```
<?php
    $groupname = 'mygroup';
    $username  = 'test';
    $password  = crypt('Pass123!');
    var_dump($password);

    $command = "sudo useradd -G $groupname $username -p $password -s /bin/false";
    var_dump($command);

    $output = array();
    $return = 0;
    exec($command, $output, $return);

    var_dump($output);
    var_dump($return);
```

After running this script, I see the user `test` in the /etc/passwd file. However, I don't see password in the /etc/shadow file. My gut feeling is that I am incorrectly setting the password somehow.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

When I create the user via the command line and add the password using `passwd` command, the encrypted string I see in /etc/shadow is very different from what the `crypt` function in my PHP script generates.

**UPDATE 2**

Per `mario`'s suggestion:

```
<?php
    $groupname = 'mygroup';
    $username  = 'test';
    $password  = crypt('Pass123!');
    var_dump($password);

    $command = "sudo useradd -G '$groupname' '$username' -p '$password' -s /bin/false";
    $command = escapeshellcmd($command);
    var_dump($command);

    $output = array();
    $return = 0;
    exec($command, $output, $return);

    var_dump($output);
    var_dump($return);
```

NOTE: this has not fixed anything for me. Problem is still the same.

Comment: which user is executing the php script, has he the rights to do sudo useradd without a password ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that the `crypt()` hash starts with `$1$abc..` usually. And your parameters for the command to `exec()` are not escaped. At the very least quote them:

```
$command = "sudo useradd -G '$groupname' '$username' -p '$password'  ";
```

But you should use `escapeshellcmd()` on each preferrably.

The hash you get back from PHPs `crypt()` is not necessarily the same as the `passwd` utility would generate it. There are different hash functions. PHP gives you the MD5 version (starting with `$1$`), whereas `passwd` might default to generating SHA512 hashes (starting with `$6$`).

See the examples on http://php.net/crypt with algorithm and salt parameters.

Comment: You are not supposed to use escapeshellcmd on the whole $command, but on each parameter individually ($username, $password). But leave it out for now. Quoting suffices to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to crypt your password with a perl script :

`$command = "sudo useradd -G ".$groupname." ".$username." -p $(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], \"password\")' ".password.") -s /bin/false";`